# I'm trying to find an element through xpath by selenium in my code

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find the element "BANK STATEMENT - Company" through xpath by selenium in my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label style="margin-left: 20px;">Please upload relevant documents</label>
<br>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <div class="icheckbox_minimal" style="position: relative;" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false">
        <input id="document_type_id1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="document_type_id[]" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
    </div>
    BANK STATEMENT - Company
</label>
```

The closest that i reached is this by writing the below xpath. But its not helpful

```
//form[@id='w1']/descendant::label[@class='checkbox-inline']
```

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Please show us the complete code. Your HTML isn't well formed.

Comment: This tool is very helpful.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the *text content* of an element node, which can be selected with `text()`. Using the HTML snippet you show,

```
//label[@class='checkbox-inline']/text()
```

will return all text nodes of that `label` element (individual results separated by `-------`):

```
[EMPTY LINE]
-----------------------
BANK STATEMENT - Company
```

As you can see, the first text node is a whitespace-only text node and it is the *second node* you'd like to retrieve from the document.

```
//label[@class='checkbox-inline']/text()[2]
```

results in

```
[EMPTY LINE]
BANK STATEMENT - Company
[EMPTY LINE]
```

because newline characters are also part of a text node. To get rid of the extra whitespace, use

```
normalize-space(//label[@class='checkbox-inline']/text()[2])
```

which, finally, will only yield

```
BANK STATEMENT - Company
```

Taking your whole document as input, the expression should be

```
normalize-space(//form[@id='w1']//label[@class='checkbox-inline']/text()[2])
```

I suppose, but we cannot check if that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mathias Müller!

The expression that you have mentioned is working when i checked it on xpath checker. 

However, when i use it in my code, it is not able to find the element. 

PS: I'm using Junit data driven framework.

Comment: @Sashi Then, please show _all_ of your HTML code - we can only help if you give complete information.

Comment: @Sashi And also, "not able" is not very informative. What _do_ you get back? An error? An unexpected result?

Comment: @Sashi, is it possible that the webpage you are working with is slow to load? Selenium may be attempting to find the element before it has been written to the DOM, and that is the reason it cannot be found.